# assigning keys to values in JQ

Tags: json, bash, command-line-interface, jq

Is there a way in jq to go from this stdout:

```
Thu Jun 9 10:09:14 AM EDT 2022IP86.75.30.9
```

to this?:

```
{
    "date": "Thu Jun 9 10:09:14 AM EDT 2022",
    "ip": "86.75.30.9"
}
```

I was able to get part of the way there

with this:

```
echo $(date)IP$(myip.sh) | jq -R 'split("IP")'
```

that outputs this:

```
[
  "Thu Jun 9 10:09:14 AM EDT 2022",
  "86.75.30.9"
]
```

thanks!!

Comment: Have you looked into jq's built-in regex support?

Comment: Or, once you have `["date", "ip"]`, you can pipe that into `{"date": .[0], "ip": .[1]}`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object with the `date` and `ip` key in which you'll assign the first and second index accordingly:

```
split("IP") | { date: .[0], ip: .[1] }
```

Will produce

```json
{
  "date": "Thu Jun 9 10:09:14 AM EDT 2022",
  "ip": "86.75.30.9"
}
```

---

###### [Online example](https://jqplay.org/s/eFY48fR6ZOu)

Comment: this worked, many thanks! I'd give you an upvote but Stack Overflow says I'm too new.

Answer (score 0):

Using `capture` might come in handy:

```bash
jq -R 'capture("(?<date>.*)IP(?<ip>.*)")'
```

```json
{
  "date": "Thu Jun 9 10:09:14 AM EDT 2022",
  "ip": "86.75.30.9"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/srQUDFBQrWg)

Answer (score 0):

Mixing [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) with [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```bash
line='Thu Jun 9 10:09:14 AM EDT 2022IP86.75.30.9'
jq -n --arg date "${line%IP*}" --arg ip "${line#*IP}" '$ARGS.named'
```

```json
{
  "date": "Thu Jun 9 10:09:14 AM EDT 2022",
  "ip": "86.75.30.9"
}
```